# R's caret training errors when y is not a factor

Tags: r, knn, r-caret, categorical-data, training-data

I am using R-studio and am using kaggle's [forest cover data](http://www.kaggle.com/c/forest-cover-type-prediction/data) and keep getting an error when trying to use the knn3 function in caret.  here is my code:

```
library(caret)
train <- read.csv("C:/data/forest_cover/train.csv", header=T)
trainingRows <- createDataPartition(train$Cover_Type, p=0.8, list=F)
head(trainingRows)
train_train <- train[trainingRows,]
train_test <- train[-trainingRows,]

knnfit <- knn3(train_train[,-56], train_train$Cover_Type)
```

This last line gives me this in the console:

```
Error in knn3.matrix(x, y = y, k = k, ...) : y must be a factor
```

Comment: What does `class(train_train$Cover_Type)` return? I'm guessing not a factor.

Comment: @MrFlick "integer", how do I fix that?  I am very new to R sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, `y` must be a factor (here, `y` is the name of the second parameter to the function). In R, a factor variable is used to represent categorical data. You can turn `y` into a factor with `factor(y)` but it will just have the levels `1:7` for your  data. If you want to give more meaningful values to your factor, try

```
train$Cover_Type <- factor(train$Cover_Type, levels=1:7, 
    labels=c("Spruce/Fir","Lodgepole Pine","Ponderosa Pine",
    "Cottonwood/Willow","Aspen",
    "Douglas-fir","Krummholz"))
```

That will make your function happier and give you more useful labels in the results